# Can use AWS CLI with credentials file but not with environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I usually use my AWS CLI commands after setting a profile, with the environment variable `AWS_PROFILE`, with the `~/.aws/credentials` file. This works.

What I'm currently trying to do is to set up access via environment variables. To do so, I'm setting those variables in my `.bash_profile` file - I literally copied the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` entries from the credentials files and put them in my `bash_profile` file, under the names of `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

The environment variables are being correctly set, and, yet, when I try to access AWS resources (in this case, I'm trying to run a `ls` S3 command over a bucket, so the region doesn't matter), I get the message

```
An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records
```

which is very weird to me, since the keys are exactly the same. To confirm this, I switch to my credential profile with the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable, and then the command works normally.

I suspected that, somehow, I was setting the wrong environment variables, or something like that. Then, I read this [AWS guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/access-key-does-not-exist/#:%7E:text=The%20error%20message%20%22The%20AWS,user%20might%20have%20been%20deleted.), and ran the command `aws configure list`, which, in the first case (the case with environment variables only), returned

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************AAAA              env
secret_key     ****************AAAA              env
    region                us-east-1              env    ['AWS_REGION', 'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
```

For the second case (with the profile set), it returned

```
     Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile              dev-staging           manual    --profile
access_key     ****************AAAA shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************AAAA shared-credentials-file
    region                us-east-1              env    ['AWS_REGION', 'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
```

In other words, the environment variables are being correctly set, the AWS CLI acknowledges them, their values are the same as when they are set via the credentials file, and, yet, for some reason, it doesn't work that way.

I thought it could be due to the aws_session_token, which I also tried to set as an environment variable, to no avail.

I need to access AWS resources this way to simulate the environment in which my code will run, and I don't see why this would not work the way I'm intending.

Any ideas on how to solve it are appreciated.

Comment: " put them in my bash_profile" - how did you put them? Did you export them from there?

Comment: Yes, I exported them. They are being correctly set, I can access them from a new terminal session. They even show up on the `aws configure list` for new sessions, so that part is working...

Comment: Why do you mean by `aws_session_token`? This is only for temporary credentials. Why would you have it if you use IAM user credentails, i guess?

Comment: Well, at that point, all logical explanations had been exhausted, I was only trying random things that I thought could explain what was happening. It was irrelevant anyway, having it there or not. Matter of fact is I still don't understand why I cannot access AWS resources if the credentials are the same, only differing in where they come from.

Comment: From you description, your setup is correct and in theory should work. Can you run `env | grep AWS` in console and verify that the credentials were correctly exported, they are not missing a single character, or were not overwritten by some other exports?

Comment: Yep, ran that, and they are correctly set. Their ending is correct, and so is their beginning. I even copied the text, printed right below, same text. Exporting the variables directly in the session also doesn't make it work.

Comment: Can you run `aws s3 ls --debug`. In the resulting printout there should be info about credentails used, e.g. `Looking for credentials via` or `Found credentials in environment variables` to check what is actually used in your case.

Comment: Believe me or not, that command broke with the same message lol

Comment: Yes, but should print out bunch of stuff before it crashed? Somewhere there there should be info about the credentails, where are they coming from.

Comment: Access key used also should be there, not secret key.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone stumbles on this, a possible culprit for this might be the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` and `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN` environment variables.

If you were using different `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables before and an `AWS CLI` command is run, directly or indirectly, then after first auth the above two token variables are set. And after we overwrite the existing `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` with new values, the older token variables still remain as they are and `AWS CLI` doesn't have an explicit check to see if the access/secret keys were updated and it continues to use older tokens resulting in older keys being used internally and will continue to do so till the tokens expire.
The `aws configure` will continue to show new access keys, but internally it would be using older access keys because of cached tokens.

So if you want to continue to use the environment variables in such scenarios you will need to `unset` the two environment variables containing tokens and in your case also add an `unset` command for two token variables after setting the new access/secret keys in environment variables.

```
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
unset AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN
```

This behavior is one of the reasons people prefer to use different profiles either using `aws configure` or editing the `~/.aws/*` files, and explicitly specify them using the `--profile` in commands instead of using environment variables.

Per the [AWS cli configuration precedence order](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence) the usage of `~/.aws/config` file is at the top of the precedence order of where AWS CLI picks up the auth to be used, so it overrides the token environment variables and works in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your ~/.aws/config file when you would like to refer to the credentials from environment variables instead of **credentials** file.

With AWS Access Keys in credentials file, you must be having profile setup as OR there is no such `source_profile` config for any profile:

```
[default]
source_profile = default
```

However, when you would like to use the credentials set in your environment variables or bash_profile, change/add this setting to every profile in your config file:

```
[default]
credential_source = Environment
```

With this change, it should work with your Environment variables as well.

In case you've multiple profiles in **~/.aws/config** file, just replace/add `source_profile = <profile-name>` with `credential_source = Environment`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222273/discussion-between-kk-and-lucas-lima).